# Is there a way to zoom in on a sliderInput for more precision in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Let's suppose that my `min` is 0 and my `max` is 100,000,000,000. I need precision down to 1. How can that be achieved with `sliderInput`?

Comment: I wouldn't know a way to do this with the standard `sliderInput`, maybe you can use several sliders for the different precisions (one for 0/10000000/.../100000000, one for 0/100000/1000000 etc.) that are conditionally shown?

Comment: Why didn't you accept the nice answer posted by @HubertL?

Answer (score 1):

Your mouse (or finger) aren't precise enough to achieve this in one slider, but as proposed by @starja, you could uses several ones.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    sliderInput("billions", "Billions", min = 0, max = 10^11 - 10^9, value = 0, step = 10^9, width = 1000 ),
    sliderInput("millions", "Millions", min = 0, max = 10^9 - 10^6, value = 0, step = 10^6, width = 1000 ),
    sliderInput("thousands", "Thousands", min = 0, max = 10^6 - 1000, value = 0, step = 10^3, width = 1000 ),
    sliderInput("units", "Units", min = 0, max = 10^3-1, value = 0, step = 1, width = 1000 ),
    verbatimTextOutput("result")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(scipen=999)
  output$result <- renderPrint(input$billions + input$millions + input$thousands + input$units)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: app]

One issue with this solution is that you can either have values between 0 and 99 999 999 999, or 199 999 999 999...